# How to interface a camera with a 4-pin aviation connector?

Tags: pcb, connector, camera, development, encoding

I'd like to use this kind camera on a development board.
[image]

I want to make an invention and I need to use this specific camera, but none of the development boards that exist (from Arduino to the more complex like STM32, ARM A53, FPGAs, etc) have this type of connector (**4-pin aviation connector**), and I have not found any expansion board either to provide a common board with connectivity with this type of camera.

**Anyone know how I can connect this camera to a development board?**

I was thinking in designing my own PCB, the problem is that it's not just placing the connector and wires and it's done: No, it is not like that, I beli that it would also be necessary to place its PHY and such.
In addition, I'm not sure how to decode the video signal from that camera either, although I suspect that it must use PAL or NTSC encoding.

Well, any help is more than welcome.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Would you add the make, model, or link to such a camera, otherwise it could be any random camera with any random inteface (analog, USB, Ethernet) on that specific connector.

Comment: A quick search turns up something on Amazon that at least looks like it could be the same camera: https://www.amazon.co.uk/Quality-Reversing-Vehicle-Caravans-Waterproof/dp/B00E2OJ1W8. If so, one of the pictures there shows what the four pins on the connector are (2 power, 2 analog video).

Comment: It looks like analog camera for car  reverse. Powered  by 12v, but to get color you should find out video signal standart.